# If search contains string

Tags: php, mysql

I have been using this little template since a few years back

```
// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
$hint = "";
session_start();
require ('connect.php');
$get_qst = mysql_query("SELECT question FROM questions WHERE question LIKE '%$q%'") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($get_qst) >= 1) {
    while ($qst = mysql_fetch_array($get_qst)) {
        $a[] = $qst['question'];
    }
}
else {
    $a[] = "";
}
// Fill up array with names

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from ""
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len = strlen($q);
    foreach ($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = $name;
            }
            else {
                $hint .= "<br /> $name";
            }
        }
    }
}
// Output "no suggestion" if no hint were found
// or output the correct values

echo $hint === "" ? 'No questions found, <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn_askqst" onclick="$(\'#qst\').val($(\'#search_qst\').val());">ask question?</a>' : $hint;
```

And what the code does is to compare a input field to rows in the database. The problem is that for example ff I have a question in my database saying "What do you prefer PHP or ASP?" and someone searches for "PHP or ASP?" it will say there are no questions. The reason to this is that it doesn't check for single words, it checks just the beginning of the sentence. So for me to see this I need to write every word in the right order, though I do not need to write the whole question.

How do I do so it detects if the word is in the question at all?

I am sorry for bad explaining. English isn't my first language and I don't really know how to explain this.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

First, you would need to break the input string at the spaces:

```
$q  = "PHP or ASP";
$terms = explode(" ", $q);
```

Then, you'll need to perform the search query for each word.

```
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $get_qst = mysql_query("SELECT question FROM questions WHERE question LIKE '%$term%'") or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($get_qst) >= 1) {
        while ($qst = mysql_fetch_array($get_qst)) {
            $a[] = $qst['question'];
        }
    }
    else {
        $a[] = "";
    }
}
```

Finally, and this is important, rework this code to stop using mysql_ functions. See the comment above from @h2ooooooo